# Is't Possible to create phonegap application without Jquery Mobile or any other UI Frameworks

Tags: jquery, html, css, cordova

I want to create classified site in mobile application including android, blackberry and iOS platform.
Am choosing Phonegap framework, html, jquery, css.

I have doubts "Is't Possible to create phonegap application without Jquery Mobile or any other UI Frameworks"

Please suggest me. If I include Jquery Mobile js and css design will collapsed and enable to achieve my requirement. without JQuery Mobile works good.

My doubt is Is there any way to complete the application without JQuery Mobile or any other UI Frameworks.

Please suggest me.

Comment: The question is not quite clear to me. Sure, you can create an application without any framework but it will be a lot more work. Maybe you should just try to fix the _If I include Jquery Mobile js and css design will collapsed_ problem?

Comment: Thanks Tim,
Designer already created html, css files. Designer formed pages and page transitions without jquery mobile working fine. Problem is I include JQuery Mobile now. My doubt is Is't Possible to I complete the mobile application without using JQuery Mobile or any other UI Framework.
Or Shall I include only JQuery Mobile js only.

Comment: If it's all done and jQuery mobile wasn't used, why would you include now anyway? Why do you think you have to include it at all?

Answer (score 2):

PhoneGap does not care about any frameworks as long as its built using HTML,CSS and JavaScript. JQM is just a wrapper on top of these 3. its helps you to prevent you from re inventing the wheel. So you are good to go with your pure HTML app on PhoneGap.

Comment: I am also started to develop a simple app ui framework with page transitions for PhoneGap ;).